# How to restart a child process from parent process in c

Tags: c

How to restart the child process from parent process when child process terminates. In one application I have created a child process which has an infinite while loop. The application runs in a router. When some event happens my child process terminates. But after rebooting the router everything works fine. Is it possible to restart my child process from parent process(parent process always works).

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            printf("Child process\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            printf("parrent process\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a process is terminated, it cannot be restarted. (A new process running the same executable can be started, but that's a different thing.)  If a process is stopped, it can be restarted.

Comment: is it possible for parent process to know that child has terminated, so that first process can reboot the application.

Comment: When the child terminates, the parent receives SIGCHLD.

Comment: @WilliamPursell (If a process is stopped, it can be restarted). How give me some explaination.

Comment: If a process receives SIGSTOP or SIGTSTP, it stops.  It will resume when it receives SIGCONT.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only start one process and it's another executable:

```
pid_t pid = 0;
void sigchld(int unused)
{
    if (pid) {
        int status = 0;
        waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status) || WIFCONTINUED(status)) return;
        if (!WIFSIGNALED(status)) return; // It exited rather than terminated
        pid = 0;
    }
    if ((pid = vfork() == 0) {
        /* fork() isn't really signal safe anymore but vfork() still is! */
        execle(...);
        _exit(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pid = 0;
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = sigchld;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
    kill(SIGCHLD, getpid());
    while(1)
    {
        printf("parrent process\n");
    }
}
```

Trivially adaptable to more than one, but if it's not another executable you have your work cut out from you. Attempting to `fork()` and run more code inside the signal handler is fraught with pearl. `fork()` itself is only safe if you haven't installed any `pthread_atfork()` handlers (which don't run in `vfork()`). You cannot call `malloc()` in a signal handler, and stdio is unreasonably tricky and best to assume it just doesn't work.